# Twelve Minesweeper mines that make twelve 4s

Tags: logical-deduction, minesweeper

Can you place twelve mines on a Minesweeper grid such that they create twelve 4s? The size of the grid can be arbitrary. The mines may create numbers other than 4s, but those are irrelevant.

Good luck!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about (horrible ascii depiction):

> ```
> ..*..*..
> .444444.
> ********
> .444444.
> ..*..*..
> ```

Comment: That's correct! Well done.

Comment: Nice, couldn't figure it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question and its generalizations (more mines in larger grids) can be found in my sequence here:

https://oeis.org/A302928

The actual solutions are here:

https://oeis.org/A302928/a302928.txt